# Calculate the mean value using two columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a deal dataframe with three columns and I have sorted by the type and date, It looks like:

```
  type    date      price
   A    2020-05-01   4
   A    2020-06-04   6
   A    2020-06-08   8
   A    2020-07-03   5
   B    2020-02-01   3
   B    2020-04-02   4
```

There are many types (A, B, C,D,E…), I want to calculate **the previous mean price of the same type of product**. For example: the pre_mean_price value of third row A is (4+6)/2=5.  I want to get a dataframe like this:

```
   type    date      price  pre_mean_price
   A    2020-05-01   4       .
   A    2020-06-04   6       4
   A    2020-06-08   8       5 
   A    2020-07-03   5       6
   B    2020-02-01   3       .
   B    2020-04-02   4       3
```

How can I calculate the pre_mean_price? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`expanding().mean()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.expanding.html) after groupby for each group , then shift the values.

```
df['pre_mean_price'] = df.groupby("type")['price'].apply(lambda x: 
                                                         x.expanding().mean().shift())
print(df)
```

---

```
  type        date  price  pre_mean_price
0    A  2020-05-01      4             NaN
1    A  2020-06-04      6             4.0
2    A  2020-06-08      8             5.0
3    A  2020-07-03      5             6.0
4    B  2020-02-01      3             NaN
5    B  2020-04-02      4             3.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like

```
df['pre_mean_price'] = df.groupby('type').expanding().mean().groupby('type').shift(1)['price'].values
```

which produces

```
  type        date  price  pre_mean_price
0    A  2020-05-01      4             NaN
1    A  2020-06-04      6             4.0
2    A  2020-06-08      8             5.0
3    A  2020-07-03      5             6.0
4    B  2020-02-01      3             NaN
5    B  2020-04-02      4             3.0
```

#### Short explanation

The idea is to

- First groupby `"type"` with `.groupby()`. This must be done since we want to calculate the (incremental) means *within* the group "type".
- Then, calculate the incremental mean with `expanding().mean()`. The output in this point is

```
        price
type
A    0   4.00
     1   5.00
     2   6.00
     3   5.75
B    4   3.00
     5   3.50
```

- Then, groupby again by `"type"`, and shift the elements inside the groups by one row with `shift(1)`.
- Then, just extract the values of the `price` column (the incremental means)
- **Note**: This assumes your data is sorted by date. It it is not, call `df.sort_values('date', inplace=True)` before.